# Delegate property gets unset?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm running into a problem that I'm not sure how to solve. Let me just give some relevant code.

**FrontpageViewController (viewDidLoad)**

```
NewsFetcher *newsFetcher = [[NewsFetcher alloc] initWithURL:url];
newsFetcher.delegate = self;
[newsFetcher loadData];
```

**NewsFetcher.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <NewsFetcherDelegate> delegate;
```

I'm using unsafe_unretained because I want my app to work with iOS 4 as well, while still using ARC for convenience.

**NewsFetcher.m**

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        self.url = url;
        self.receivedData = [[NSData alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)loadData {

    NSLog(@"%@", self.delegate); // FrontpageViewController, as expected

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url 
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                         timeoutInterval:15];

    if (self.connectionInProgress)
        [self.connectionInProgress cancel];

    self.connectionInProgress = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        startImmediately:YES];
}
```

This all works fine. NewsFetcher conforms to the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol, so the next method that's being called is `connection:didReceiveData:`. However, when I do another `NSLog(@"%@", self.delegate)` within that method, I get varied results (EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, NSCFDictionary, etc.). I think this means that my `delegate` property points to a released object, which is weird because it's supposed to be the view controller that's still on screen (and therefore couldn't have been released, right?).

How is my delegate available in one method, but not anymore in the next method? Does it have to do with the `unsafe_unretained`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate objects are not retained (by convention) by callers. The expectation is that the caller who set it on your object will retain it. Recommend you use the Instruments tool with zombies (and then with leaks) to see what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I've done this, and when I run Instruments with Zombies, it does say I send a message do a deallocated object. How come my FrontpageViewController gets released while its view is still on screen? You say the expectation is that the caller who set it will retain it, but since it doesn't do this automatically, how do I do it myself? I don't think making it a strong pointer is the desired solution here, is it?

Comment: No - don't make it a strong pointer. You should be able to zoom in on that instance and look at all the retains/releases to see what is going on. Are you displaying any modals or other display controllers? You can also look at didReceiveMemoryWarning - the default implementation will automatically release resources if they are not onscreen.

Comment: No other view controllers come into play at this time. Upon opening the app, the view controller creates an instance of NewsFetcher, which then goes to download (from local network) and parse an RSS file. By the time it's done (takes maybe a second) parsing, the delegate object (the view controller) is already gone. I have very little experience with Instruments, so any hints would be very helpful. That view controller never goes off screen, so I don't think it's low on memory (besides, I'm only testing this on the simulator).

Comment: Time spent learning Instruments is not wasted at all my friend - for the coles notes, if you can invest 45 min of your time to watch a video, highly recommend looking at the WWDC videos, both 2010 and 2011 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/), like these: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/whats-new-in-instruments.html#whats-new-in-instruments , https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=311 . Nice walkthroughs of how to fix exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Also @bbum has a great link here, but that's for retain cycles not zombies: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: I've watched both videos, and I see what part you're talking about. In the 2010 video, the guy explains how to debug an over-released object and looking at its history. In manual memory management, it's possible to go to the different retain/release calls. However, this doesn't really work for me since I'm using ARC. The only code it lets me jump into is the `application:didFnishingLaunchingWithOptions:` and `main` methods, so I can't inspect whether certain release calls are valid or not... I'm probably still missing something, but I can't for the life of me figure out what...